# Pandas: Flag column if value in list exists anywhere in row

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

Ultimately, I want to flag a new column, 'ExclusionFlag', with 0 or 1 depending on whether a value that is found in a list exists anywhere in the row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['cat','b','c','c'],['a','b','c','c'],['a','b','c','dog'],['dog','b','c','c']],columns=['Code1','Code2','Code3','Code4'])
excluded_codes = ['cat','dog']

#Attempt
df['ExclusionFlag'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'cat' in x.values, axis=1).any()

#Desired outcome
#Side note: I have 120 rows to check. They're labeled Code1, Code2...Code120. 

    Code1   Code2   Code3   Code4   ExclusionFlag
0   cat     b       c       c       1
1   a       b       c       c       0
2   a       b       c       dog     1
3   dog     b       c       c       1
```

The line of code I have marks every row as True.

And when I add the excluded_codes list in for 'cat' in my lambda expression, I get an error.

I found a couple questions like this, but what I see typically is something along the lines of (see below), which calls out a specific column, but I don't think iterating through 120 columns is the best approach. Although I could be wrong.

```
df['ExclusionFlag'] = df['Code1'].isin(exclusion_codes)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like

```
df['ExclusionFlag'] = df.isin(excluded_codes).any(1).astype(int)

    Code1   Code2   Code3   Code4   ExclusionFlag
0   cat     b       c       c       1
1   a       b       c       c       0
2   a       b       c       dog     1
3   dog     b       c       c       1
```

Comment: ah, didn't realize `.isin` was a `DataFrame` method.

Comment: Nice one, Vaishali! +1

Comment: I got an error that read: typeerror: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'   How can this been manged?

Comment: I'm wondering if its the df that I'm using. Could this issue arise when columns are of different datatypes?

Comment: hmm.. it appears that the number of values I have in my list is causing this error. I initially had 166 different values in my list, so I cut the list in half and ran both halves separately and it worked. Not entirely sure how to manage this though...

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? There was a bug with large array with isin that has been fixed. See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16969

Comment: wow. that was it. I updated pandas and now it works perfectly. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want True or False values in new column, you can check them without Any and Astype.

```
df['ExclusionFlag'] = df.isin(excluded_codes)
```

And you can check specific column also:

```
df['ExclusionFlag'] = df['Code2'].isin(excluded_codes)
```